# Magento 1.9 - Modify CMS pages that are available in one store and aren't available in another

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, cms, cms-pages

I'm looking for for a way to modify CMS pages that are available in one store and aren't available in another store. 
First problem is that I cannot filter cms pages the usual way:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
   ->addStoreFilter($oneStore)
   ->addFilter('store', array('nin' => $anotherStore->getId()), 'public');
```

Collection matches pages available for all store views ignoring 'not in' filter.

Edit: Following code gets stores that have relation with $oneStore but still it doesn't check if they have relation with $anotherStore:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
   ->addStoreFilter($oneStore, false);
$collection->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

try just

`$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($oneStore);`

without 
`->addFilter('store', array('nin' => $anotherStore->getId()), 'public');`

Comment: Same result, incorrect answer